# Running total with conditional in Pyspark/Hive

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I have product, brand and percentage columns. I want to calculate the sum of the percentage column for the rows above the current row for those with different brand than the current row and also for those with same brand as the current row. How can I do it in PySpark or using using spark.sql?

**sample data:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['a1','a2','a3','a4','a5','a6'],
              'brand':['b1','b2','b1', 'b3', 'b2','b1'],
          'pct': [40, 30, 10, 8,7,5]})
df = spark.createDataFrame(df)
```

**What I am looking for:**

```
product  brand  pct  pct_same_brand  pct_different_brand
a1       b1     40     null           null
a2       b2     30     null           40
a3       b1     10     40             30
a4       b3     8      null           80
a5       b2     7      30             58
a6       b1     5      50             45
```

This is what I have tried:

```
df.createOrReplaceTempView('tmp')
spark.sql("""
select *, sum(pct * (select case when n1.brand = n2.brand then 1 else 0 end 
from tmp n1)) over(order by pct desc rows between UNBOUNDED PRECEDING and 1 
preceding) 
from tmp n2
""").show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the `pct_different_brand` column by subtracting the total rolling sum from the partitioned rolling sum (i.e. `pct_same_brand` column):

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window

df2 = df.withColumn(
    'pct_same_brand', 
    F.sum('pct').over(
        Window.partitionBy('brand')
              .orderBy(F.desc('pct'))
              .rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, -1)
    )
).withColumn(
    'pct_different_brand', 
    F.sum('pct').over(
        Window.orderBy(F.desc('pct'))
              .rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, -1)
    ) - F.coalesce(F.col('pct_same_brand'), F.lit(0))
)

df2.show()

+---+-----+---+--------------+-------------------+
|  a|brand|pct|pct_same_brand|pct_different_brand|
+---+-----+---+--------------+-------------------+
| a1|   b1| 40|          null|               null|
| a2|   b2| 30|          null|                 40|
| a3|   b1| 10|            40|                 30|
| a4|   b3|  8|          null|                 80|
| a5|   b2|  7|            30|                 58|
| a6|   b1|  5|            50|                 45|
+---+-----+---+--------------+-------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks a million. Can you also help with accounting the price differences as noted in the edited version above?

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask a new one instead of modifying your existing question