# Weighted running total with conditional in Pyspark/Hive

Tags: pyspark, hive

I have product, brand, percentage and price columns. I want to calculate the sum of the percentage column for the rows above the current row for those with different brand than the current row and also for those with same brand as the current row. I want to weigh them by price. If the price of the products above the current row are more than the current row, I want to down-weigh it by multiplying it by 0.8. How can I do it in PySpark or using using spark.sql? The answer without using multiplying with weight is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66728239/running-total-with-conditional-in-pyspark-hive).

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['a1','a2','a3','a4','a5','a6'],
          'brand':['b1','b2','b1', 'b3', 'b2','b1'],
      'pct': [40, 30, 10, 8,7,5], 
       'price':[0.6, 1, 0.5, 0.8, 1, 0.5]})
df = spark.createDataFrame(df)
```

**What I am looking for**

```
product  brand  pct  pct_same_brand  pct_different_brand
a1       b1     40     null            null
a2       b2     30     null            40
a3       b1     10     32              30
a4       b3     8      null            80
a5       b2     7      24              58
a6       b1     5      40              45
```

**Update:**
I have added the below data points to help clarify the problem. As can be seen,  one row can be multiplied by 0.8 in one row and by 1.0 in another row.

```
  product   brand   pct  price  pct_same_brand  pct_different_brand
  a1        b1      30   0.6    null                 null
  a2        b2      20   1.3    null                 30
  a3        b1      10   0.5    30*0.8               20
  a4        b3      8    0.8    null                 60
  a5        b2      7    0.5    20*0.8               48
  a6        b1      6    0.8    30*1 + 10*1          35
  a7        b2      5    1.5    20*1 + 7*1           54
```

**Update2**: In the data that I provided above, the weight per row is the same number (0.8 or 1) but it can also be 1 and 0.8 (0.8 for some of the rows and 1 for other rows)

Example in the below data frame, the multiplier for the last row , for example, should be 0.8 for a6 and 1.0 for the rest of brand b1. :

```
  df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['a1','a2','a3','a4','a5','a6', 'a7', 'a8', 'a9', 'a10'],
          'brand':['b1','b2','b1', 'b3', 'b2','b1','b2', 'b1', 'b1', 'b1'],
          'pct': [30, 20, 10, 8, 7,6,5,4,3,2],
          'price':[0.6, 1.3, 0.5, 0.8, 0.5, 0.8, 1.5, 0.5, 0.65, 0.7]
         
         })
df = spark.createDataFrame(df)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone has a similar question, this worked for me.
Basically, I used outer join of the dataframe with itself and assigned the weights. Finally, I used window functions.

```
df_copy = df.withColumnRenamed('a', 'asin')\
        .withColumnRenamed('brand', 'brandd')\
         .withColumnRenamed('pct', 'pct2')\
         .withColumnRenamed('price', 'price2')
 df2 = df.join(df_copy, on = [df.brand == df_copy.brandd], how = 'outer').orderBy('brand')
 df3 = df2.filter(~((df2.a == df2.asin) & (df2.brand == df2.brandd))
             & (df2.pct <= df2.pct2))
 df3 = df3.withColumn('weight', F.when(df3.price2 > df3.price, 0.8).otherwise(1))

 df4 = df3.groupBy(['a', 'brand', 'pct', 'price']).agg(F.sum(df3.pct2*df3.weight)
                                        .alias('same_brand_pct'))

 df5 = df.join(df4, on = ['a', 'brand', 'pct', 'price'], how = 'left')
 df6 = df5.withColumn(
   'pct_same_brand_unscaled', 
    F.sum('pct').over(
    Window.partitionBy('brand')
          .orderBy(F.desc('pct'))
          .rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, -1)
  )
  ).withColumn(
'pct_different_brand', 
F.sum('pct').over(
    Window.orderBy(F.desc('pct'))
          .rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, -1)
  ) - F.coalesce(F.col('pct_same_brand_unscaled'), F.lit(0))
 ).drop('pct_same_brand_unscaled')
```

gives:

````
+---+-----+---+-----+--------------+-------------------+
|  a|brand|pct|price|same_brand_pct|pct_different_brand|
+---+-----+---+-----+--------------+-------------------+
| a1|   b1| 30|  0.6|          null|               null|
| a2|   b2| 20|  1.3|          null|                 30|
| a3|   b1| 10|  0.5|          24.0|                 20|
| a4|   b3|  8|  0.8|          null|                 60|
| a5|   b2|  7|  0.5|          16.0|                 48|
| a6|   b1|  6|  0.8|          40.0|                 35|
| a7|   b2|  5|  1.5|          27.0|                 54|
| a8|   b1|  4|  0.5|          38.8|                 40|
| a9|   b1|  3| 0.65|          48.8|                 40|
|a10|   b1|  2|  0.7|          51.8|                 40|```
````

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `weight` column to facilitate calculation:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window

df2 = df.withColumn(
    'weight', 
    F.when(
        F.col('price') <= F.lag('price').over(
            Window.partitionBy('brand')
                  .orderBy(F.desc('pct'))
        ), 
        0.8
    ).otherwise(1.0)
).withColumn(
    'pct_same_brand', 
    F.col('weight')*F.sum('pct').over(
        Window.partitionBy('brand')
              .orderBy(F.desc('pct'))
              .rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, -1)
    )
).withColumn(
    'pct_different_brand', 
    F.sum('pct').over(
        Window.orderBy(F.desc('pct'))
              .rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, -1)
    ) - F.coalesce(F.col('pct_same_brand'), F.lit(0)) / F.col('weight')
)

df2.show()
+---+-----+---+-----+------+--------------+-------------------+
|  a|brand|pct|price|weight|pct_same_brand|pct_different_brand|
+---+-----+---+-----+------+--------------+-------------------+
| a1|   b1| 40|  0.6|   1.0|          null|               null|
| a2|   b2| 30|  1.0|   1.0|          null|               40.0|
| a3|   b1| 10|  0.5|   0.8|          32.0|               30.0|
| a4|   b3|  8|  0.8|   1.0|          null|               80.0|
| a5|   b2|  7|  1.0|   0.8|          24.0|               58.0|
| a6|   b1|  5|  0.5|   0.8|          40.0|               45.0|
+---+-----+---+-----+------+--------------+-------------------+
```

---

Output for the edited question:

```
+---+-----+---+-----+------+--------------+-------------------+
|  a|brand|pct|price|weight|pct_same_brand|pct_different_brand|
+---+-----+---+-----+------+--------------+-------------------+
| a1|   b1| 30|  0.6|   1.0|          null|               null|
| a2|   b2| 20|  1.3|   1.0|          null|               30.0|
| a3|   b1| 10|  0.5|   0.8|          24.0|               20.0|
| a4|   b3|  8|  0.8|   1.0|          null|               60.0|
| a5|   b2|  7|  0.5|   0.8|          16.0|               48.0|
| a6|   b1|  6|  0.8|   1.0|          40.0|               35.0|
| a7|   b2|  5|  1.5|   1.0|          27.0|               54.0|
+---+-----+---+-----+------+--------------+-------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks. But one price can be less than some of them and at the same time more than others. Let's say if the price of the last row is 0.7, row 1's weight will be 0.8 for row 3 but1 for row 6.

Comment: what do you mean by "row 1's weight will be 0.8 for row 3"? Do you mean 0.8 for row 1 or row 3?

Comment: also could you clarify the rules for weighting? A complete example will be helpful, if you could edit your question to add that

Comment: I added more data points and as you can see the same row can be multiplied by 0.8 in one row and by 1 in another row.

Comment: @FissehaBerhane I checked the output of my code on the dataframe in the edited question, and it agrees with your expected output... Does the code work for you?

Comment: You are right. It works as expected for the example data I provided but the reason for that is the weight is the same per row. The weight can also be 1 for some rows and 0.8 for other rows as I have noted in update 2 with the example data and that code does not work with the new example dataframe.